# Changing Yii folder locations

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Using Yii2 Basic. I am trying to tidy-up my Yii2 installation and wish to place the main working files and folders into a sub directory on my co-hosted production server called, say, "yii2basic". I then need to place all the files and folders from the *web* folder into *public_html* on the server.

As far as I can ascertain, I only need to change the the following lines in the index.php file like so:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2basic/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../yii2basic/config/web.php');
```

Is this correct or have I missed something?

Please note I do not have access to the **httpd.conf** file on the co-hosted server so cannot make changes to it.

I have searched for an answer to this on this site and in the manual but cannot find one. It's possible that the question is incorrectly phrased. If so, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a number of files with the correct new url

To start Off you need to change the following files

> 1. index.php
> 2. index-test.php
> 3. yii.php //to be able run yii on console/terminal
> 4. requirements.php

Then you're good to go

Comment: @JQL try this out and if you encounter any issues we can always sort it out

Comment: I've made the changes to index.php, index-test.php and requirements.php ($frameworkPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/yii2basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2';). I don't seem to be able to find a path to change it the yii.php file.

Comment: @JQL there is line 17 and 18  confirm the yii.php is on /basic/yii.php not the on on vendor/yii2soft/yii2 folder

Comment: I forgot to mention that to have application just running changing index.php as you have done will get things working  but as I have highlighted the other files are also important if you are using console or running a cronjob and if you have test scrips @JQL